# charts.js add data with date

Tags: javascript, arrays, chart.js

So Im trying to find an smart way to pass data with dates to chart.js.
On the x-axis i would like to show a time line for example a week,

14/06 15/06 16/06 17/06 18/06 19/06 20/6

But the data will not inculde every day
for example

[{'date': 15/06, 'bought': 2}, {'date': 17/06, 'bought': 5}]

for what I read, I would need to create a new array (same index number as the time period), compare the dates and replace the value depending on the index value...
Is there a better process?
I would like to show a time period for like a year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LeeLenalee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8682983/leelenalee)'s perfectly shows how Chart.js is instructed to correctly parse your data. In order to obtain a time line, you'll also need to define the x-axis as a [time cartesian axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html).

Please take a look at below runnable code and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Purchases per day',
      data: [
        { 'date': '15/06', 'bought': 2 }, 
        { 'date': '17/06', 'bought': 5 }, 
        { 'date': '20/06', 'bought': 3 }
      ],
      borderColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 255)',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    parsing: {
      xAxisKey: 'date',
      yAxisKey: 'bought'
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 1
        }
      },
      x: {
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          parser: 'DD/MM',
          unit: 'day',
          tooltipFormat:'MMM DD'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.3.2/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.27.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment@0.1.1"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just provide that array as is to chart.js, you only need to specify which field should be mapped to the x Axis and which field to the yAxis in the parsing block of the options object.

Live example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [
        {
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [{'date': '15/06', 'bought': 2}, {'date': '17/06', 'bought': 5}, {'date': '20/06', 'bought': 3}],
        borderWidth: 1
        }
        ]
  },
  options: {
    parsing: {
        xAxisKey: 'date',
      yAxisKey: 'bought'
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.3.2/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```